# new window with c++ qt

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2022

i need create a button to open a new window in microsoft visual studio 2022 with qt c++

i'm trying to create a new class in qt with class cpp,H, and UI, but i'dont know connected this class for my button[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rItvP.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH7nl.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3GAS.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy9Dw.png) this is my full code, i'm brazilian my inglish is worst, but i'm trying to write, can you help me with my code?

Comment: What code? Images are not code.

Comment: To make an additional window you create a class (which is some type of QWidget) similar to your MainWindow class and dynamically create an instance of this in some slot you have in your MainWindow.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)